# Route not being defined laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I pushed this from my working dev to production and I'm now getting an error on menu.blade.php that `Route [Markets.Login] is not defined`.

I don't understand how it works fine in dev and now I'm getting an error but I can't seem to rectify it. What exactly do I have incorrect here?

**Menu.blade.php**

```
<li title="Markets">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="menu_icon"><i class="material-icons">&#xE871;</i></span>
        <span class="menu_title">Markets</span>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('Markets.Login') }}">Create Marketing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('Markets.library') }}">Marketing Library</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**routes.markets.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'campaigns', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

    Route::get('Login', 'MarketsController@Login')
        ->name('Markets.Login');

    Route::post('library', 'MarketsController@library')
        ->name('Markets.library');
});
```

Comment: You sure the Login method in MarketsController is uppercased? Cause I see you have it uppercased there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you clear the route cache on deployment? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Oh no, I've never used that before. Will that affect anything else negatively?

Comment: it just clears the route cache https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#route-caching
usually these things are cache related, or composer autoload related, but I'm assuming that composer is run on deployment

Comment: otherwise it's normally a typo for me, but that all looks fine (though my ocd is triggered at the case differences between Login and library haha)

Comment: @loonytoons Your OCD might be causing this then. Check the casing matches the method name in the Controller class.

Comment: fair point on the OCD, I have updated my code to keep the case the same although I found my issue and my main routes.php file was not including the new routes file :/  Got it going now, thanks!

Comment: ah sweet, I'd assumed it was the same routes file that was working for the library route. Glad you got it sorted :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Route name. I got this error everytime when i get into production.

For example if a route **'signup'** not working, simply change it as **'signup-page'** like that.

It will be works.

Its happening because of duplicate routes caching. Even we tried to clear the route cache too it doesn't work sometimes.